# How to send one time login url with Rules?

Tags: 7, rules

I have a rule to create a user and an action to send login url to user's email. I didn't find any action to send login url, so added an *Send HTML Email* action and added the `[user-created:one-time-login-url]` token in mail body. but it appears as it is(*[user-created:one-time-login-url]*), and is not translated to login url.

Then I used this php function to print the same url:

```
<?php
print user_pass_reset_url($user_created); 
?>
```

It prints a url but also prints the following notices:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$uid in user_pass_reset_url() (in line 2299 /var/www/web/modules/user/user.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$pass in user_pass_reset_url() (in line 2299 /var/www/web/modules/user/user.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$login in user_pass_reset_url() (in line 2299 /var/www/web/modules/user/user.module).
```

`$user_created` is the php variable referring to the user created in the previous action. But it seems it's not a user object(because of notices).

What's the proper way to send one time login url?

Comment: If $user_created is the UID variable, you will need to load the user object like this: $user = user_load($user_created); Then you can use your other function like: user_pass_reset_url($user);

Comment: tried that but this time I get some fatal errors

Answer (score 4):

Try out [Login one time](http://drupal.org/project/login_one_time) module

> The use case for this is where your users can't figure out how to use
>   a username and password - so they request an email link to what they
>   need.

Comment: using this module with _recipient user_ field set to `user-created` value still prints the same notices.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the token_replace function like this

```
$newly_created_user = user_load(101);
$subject =token_replace('Hello  [user:field-your-first-name]  [user:field-your-last-name], here is your password reset link [user:one-time-login-url] ', array('user' => $newly_created_user), array('callback' => 'user_mail_tokens', 'sanitize' => FALSE));
```

ultimately you need to add extra third parameter to the token_replace function

```
array('callback' => 'user_mail_tokens', 'sanitize' => FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was adding an `Save entity` action before using `user_pass_reset_url()` function or login one time action.